# Simple PHP counter - how to print numbers with loop?

Tags: php, for-loop

How can I print out the numbers from `0` to `20` with a loop in PHP?

I hope some one can help.

Thanks!

Comment: This question worths a bounty of 1 million!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a *for* loop:

```
for ($i = 0; $i <= 20; $i++)
{
    echo $i . "\n";
}
```

Comment: Is there a Stack Overflow policy for not answering questions when they are someone's homework?

Comment: Try it. It stops printing at 20. But it does loop 21 times which is okay since the question states it needs to stop at 20, not how many iterations it takes.

Answer (score 3):

You want a for loop:
http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php